# Does Firebase Network monitoring take into account request that time out

Tags: firebase-performance

As written in the documentation:

```
"Firebase Performance Monitoring:
Automatically measure app startup time, HTTP/S network requests, and more"
```

This is quite a useful feature and from my observations HTTP/S network requests monitoring, works along with Retrofit and OkHttpClient. But what I can not seem to find ether in the console or in the docs is what happens with requests that time out, do these show up in response time statistics or are they logged somewhere else?
If of value my settings for HttpClient are

```
.connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

It was decided to keep them that low since taking more that 5 seconds to respond has similar effect on our users as errors, basically it breaks the UX. In short increasing these values is not an option and this was a business decision.

Can we trust Firebase Performance to log and report these or do we need custom handling of this network case (like log a Non Fatal error with Crashlytics or something like that)?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Performance does account for timeout duration when calculating the median duration. For eg. If there was a connection timeout in 5 seconds, Firebase Performance does account for the 5 seconds as a part of the median network duration calculation.